# Select a random position on the border of an array

Tags: python, optimization

I've initialized an array of zeros. I'd now like to randomly select positions on the border of the array. If the position is 0, I would then set it to 1, while if it is 1, I would do nothing and repeat the process.

Here's what I currently have:

```
D = 50 # lattice dims
N = 200 # total number of particles at the end
a = np.zeros((D,D)) # playing board array

# place particle at the center of the board
a[int(D/2), int(D/2)] = 1

border_list = [0, 1, 2, 3]

i = 0
while i < N:
    border = random.choice(border_list)
    pos = math.floor((D)*random.random())
    if border == 0:
        if a[0, pos] == 0:
            a[0, pos] = 1
            i += 1
    if border == 1:
        if a[pos, 0] == 0:
            a[pos, 0] = 1
            i += 1
    if border == 2:
        if a[int(D-1), pos] == 0:
            a[int(D-1), pos] = 1
            i += 1
    if border == 3:
        if a[pos, int(D-1)] == 0:
            a[pos, int(D-1)] = 1
            i += 1
```

Seems pretty inefficient to me. Any advice regarding improving it?

Comment: "Seems pretty inefficient to me." - based on what?

Comment: @alfasin I have a lot of if statements. I'm also a relatively inexperienced programmer.

Comment: It's verbose, non-DRY... but not inefficient. You can make it more *succint* (and it would be good to do so), but the only way it'd be *faster* is to replace 3 of the `if` with `elif`, and precalculate `int(D-1)` into a variable. However, fixing *working* code is the job of [CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com), not of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Still, here's a way to DRY it out: `x` = random up to `D`, `y` = random up to `2`, times `(D - 1)` (so either `0` or `D - 1`). Then take another random up to `2` and if `0`, switch `x` and `y`. Then do what you have to with `a[x, y]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewritten from comments:

```
almostD = D - 1
choices_for_y = [0, almostD]
i = 0
while i < D:
    x = random.randint(0, almostD)      # anywhere horisontally
    y = random.choice(choices_for_y)    # top or bottom
    if random.random() < 0.5:           # flip x and y in half the cases
        x, y = y, x
    if a[x, y] == 0:
        a[x, y] = 1
        i += 1
```

However, note that this, just like your code, has double the chances of placing a dot in corners than along the edge. Also note that this is not much speedup vs your code; just less lines.

Comment: Oh wow, this is nice. Conveniently, it provides a great setup regarding where I have to take the code next. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is no efficiency issue with this code, it can be improved a bit:

```
...
while i < N:
    border = random.choice(border_list)
    pos = math.floor((D)*random.random())
    if border == 0 and a[0, pos] == 0:
        a[0, pos] = 1
        i += 1
    elif border == 1 and a[pos, 0] == 0:
        a[pos, 0] = 1
        i += 1
    elif border == 2 and a[int(D-1), pos] == 0:
        a[int(D-1), pos] = 1
        i += 1
    elif border == 3 and a[pos, int(D-1)] == 0:
        a[pos, int(D-1)] = 1
        i += 1
```

This way if one of the `if` cases evaluates to `True` the following cases will not be checked.